# PHP How to create simple hook?

Tags: php, html, callback

I already tried to Google how to do this, but I still can't figure it out. How do I create a simple hook inside PHP? Here is what I've tried so far:

**wrapper.php** (application starts here)

```
<?php   require 'core.php';   ?>
<?php   require 'view.php';   ?>
```

**core.php**

```
<?php

$hooks['hook_head'] = array();

//supposed to insert action in $hooks
function addHook($hookName, $funct){
    global $hooks;
    array_push($hooks[$hookName], $funct);
}


//supposed to execute specific hook
function executeHook($hookname){
    global $hooks;
    foreach($hooks[$hookname] as $funct){
        call_user_func( $funct );
    }
}

//supposed to execute action in $hooks when array key = hook_head
function hook_head(){
    global $hooks;
    if (array_key_exists('hook_head', $hooks)) {
        executeHook( 'hook_head' );
    }
}

//supposed to execute action in $hooks when array key == hook_footer
function hook_footer(){
    global $hooks;
    if (array_key_exists('hook_footer', $hooks)) {
        executeHook( 'hook_footer' );
    }
}

?>
```

**view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <?php   hook_head();  ?>
</head>
<body>
    <hr />

    <?php
        //add action to hook start here
        $test = function(){    echo "test succeds";    };
        addHook('hook_head', $test);
    ?>

    <?php  hook_footer();  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works fine if I insert an action inside `$hooks['hook_head']`, before I call `hook_head()`. What I actually am trying to do though, is insert the action after I called `hook_head()`. How do I do this?

Comment: Not sure you know what a hook is.

Comment: You do want to have multiple functions for each 'hookname' right?

Comment: @FaddishWorm well, i begin to doubt i know about hook. i just want to echo something in tag head from body tag.

Comment: @robbmj i want to have multiple function each hookname

Comment: i think everything i wrote in core.php its wrong at all. it just the  best i can do T-T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `addHook` call to before the `hook_head` call (preferably to the beginning of the file).

I did notice that you "want to start coding (insert action in hook head) after it call hook_head()", but that's very cumbersome. It would look something like that:

- Change `hook_head()` to insert some kind of token into the output.
- At the end of the script,

  1. call [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to get the output buffer of the page.
  2. For each hook:

     1. Execute the hook.
     2. Call [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) again to get the output buffer of the hook.
     3. Replace the appropriate token in the oputput buffer of the page with the output buffer of the hook.
  3. Print the output buffer of the page.

As I said: cumbersome. I strongly advice against it. I only mentioned it because you asked specifically. It contradicts the intuitive control flow of

1. Input
2. Processing
3. Output

Comment: i think about it too, that its not possible, can i do something maybe change everything in core.php or do anything to make it possible?

Comment: Well, ... it is actually possible, but I really don't want to talk about it.